# WebUtility.HtmlEncode doesn't convert `:`

Tags: c#, .net, url, html-entities, html-encode

I do a request to a REST web service. The web service accepts a date parameter in the following format:

```
?date=0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

The web service only accepts if the colons in the parameter are converted to %3A as follows

```
?date=0001-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z
```

I believe I could use `WebUtility.HtmlEncode()` for this conversion. But after using it, the colons aren't parsed to %3A.

Am I missing something? How can I get the parameter in the following format?

```
?date=0001-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z
```

I already lost a lot of time for this simple thing, I don't want to write code for doing only this... There must be some .NET library which already can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is a valid character in HTML, which is why `HtmlEncode` isn't touching it.  You're dealing with a URL, so you need [`UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var url = WebUtility.UrlEncode(":"); //%3A
```

Comment: I manually changed it, thanks. The problem is, when I use UrlEncode(), then it converts all special characters. And a new Uri() .NET object isn't accepting it neither